# Android thread wait until visible

Tags: android, multithreading, android-animation

I've made a custom pie chart view that I want to animate starting when the pie chart is visible. Currently what I have is the pie chart animating but by the time you can actually see it on the screen the animation is half over. This is what I have:

```
public class SinglePieChart extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    // Chart setting variables
    private int emptyCircleCol, strokeColor, number, total;

    // Paint for drawing custom view
    private Paint circlePaint;

    private RectF rect;

    private Context context;
    private AnimThread animThread;
    private SurfaceHolder holder;

    // animation variables
    private float speed;
    private float current = 0.0f;
    private boolean percentsCalculated = false;
    private float degree;
    private int viewWidth, viewHeight;

    public SinglePieChart(Context ctx, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(ctx, attrs);

        context = ctx;

        // Paint object for drawing in doDraw
        circlePaint = new Paint();
        circlePaint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
        circlePaint.setStrokeWidth(3);
        circlePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        circlePaint.setDither(true);


        rect = new RectF();

        //get the attributes specified in attrs.xml using the name we included
        TypedArray a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
            R.styleable.DashboardChartSmall, 0, 0);

        try {
            //get the colors specified using the names in attrs.xml
            emptyCircleCol = a.getColor(R.styleable.DashboardChartSmall_smCircleColor, 0xFF65676E); // light gray is default
            strokeColor    = a.getColor(R.styleable.DashboardChartSmall_smColor, 0xFF39B54A); // green is default

            // Default number values
            total  = a.getInteger(R.styleable.DashboardChartSmall_smTotal,  1);
            number = a.getInteger(R.styleable.DashboardChartSmall_smNumber, 0);
        } finally {
            a.recycle();
        }

        this.setZOrderOnTop(true);

        holder = getHolder();
        holder.setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT);

        holder.addCallback(this);
    }

    protected void calculateValues() {
        degree = 360 * number / total;
        percentsCalculated = true;
        speed = 10 * number / total;
        viewWidth  = this.getMeasuredWidth();
        viewHeight = this.getMeasuredHeight();

        float top, left, bottom, right;

        if (viewWidth < viewHeight) {
            left = 4;
            right = viewWidth - 4;
            top = ((viewHeight - viewWidth) / 2) + 4;
            bottom = viewHeight - top;
        } else {
            top = 4;
            bottom = viewHeight - 4;
            left = ((viewWidth - viewHeight) / 2) + 4;
            right = viewWidth - left;
        }

        rect.set(left, top, right, bottom);
    }

    protected void doDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        if (total == 0) {
            // Number values are not ready 
            animThread.setRunning(false);
            return;
        }

        if (!percentsCalculated) {
            calculateValues();
        }

        // set the paint color using the circle color specified
        float last = current;
        float start = -90;

        circlePaint.setColor(strokeColor);
        canvas.drawArc(rect, start, (last > degree) ? degree : last, false, circlePaint);
        start += (last > number) ? number : last;
        last = (last < number) ? 0 : last - number;

        circlePaint.setColor(emptyCircleCol);

        if (current > 360) {
            current = 360;
        }

        canvas.drawArc(rect, start, 360 - current, false, circlePaint);     

        current += speed;

        if (last > 0 || number == 0) {
            // we're done
            animThread.setRunning(false);
        }
    }

    public void setNumbers(int num, int tot) {
        number = num;
        total  = tot;

        invalidate();
        requestLayout();
    }


    public void setColor(int col) {
        strokeColor = col;
    }

    public void redraw() {
        calculateValues();
        animThread.setRunning(true);

        invalidate();
        requestLayout();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
        animThread = new AnimThread(holder, context, this);
        animThread.setRunning(true);
        animThread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
        animThread.setRunning(false);

        boolean retry = true;

        while(retry) {
            try {
                animThread.join();
                retry = false;
            } catch(Exception e) {
                Log.v("Exception Occured", e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    public class AnimThread extends Thread {
        boolean mRun;
        Canvas mcanvas;
        SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
        Context context;
        SinglePieChart msurfacePanel;

        public AnimThread(SurfaceHolder sholder, Context ctx, SinglePieChart spanel) {
            surfaceHolder = sholder;
            context = ctx;
            mRun = false;
            msurfacePanel = spanel;
        }

        void setRunning(boolean bRun) {
            mRun = bRun;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            super.run();
            while (mRun) {
                mcanvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
                if (mcanvas != null) {
                    msurfacePanel.doDraw(mcanvas);
                    surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(mcanvas);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also if you see any programming errors, memory leaks, poor performing code, please let me know. I'm new to Android.

Here is the layout that uses the SinglePieChart class:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <com.davidscoville.vokab.views.elements.SinglePieChart
            android:id="@+id/smallPieChart"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" 
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dashSmNumber"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dashSmLabel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
</merge>
```

Comment: "I've made a custom pie chart view that I want to animate starting when the pie chart is visible. Currently what I have is the pie chart animating but by the time you can actually see it on the screen the animation is half over."

Comment: do you use your custom SurfaceView inside a layout?

Comment: @blackbelt yeah. I'll add my layout to the question

Comment: we can try this way. Inside SinglePieChart create a new method, startThread in which you will execute animThread.start(); . Then, when you set your layout, retrieve the external container (I see only the merge tag) and the custom surfaceView. On the external container you can post a new Runnable. inside this runnable you should invoke yourSurfaceView.startThread()

Comment: Thanks @blackbelt that should work!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30621/discussion-between-blackbelt-and-chrislondon)

Comment: Instead of starting the animation in onSurfaceCreated method start it in onAttachedToWindow method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alright I'm going with the my pie chart won't automatically animate and it will have a new function that the Activity will trigger to start animating once it's ready. I wish there was an easier way...

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can use the [animation framework](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/overview.html)(or [nine old androids](http://nineoldandroids.com/) if you want to support older apis).  This will allow you to animate properties on your view, in your case the start and current variables.

I'd set this to happen during [onAttachedToWindow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html#onAttachedToWindow).

Note if you aren't doing a lot of other things in this pie chart a surfaceview might be overkill for your needs.